# Converting array characters in C Programming

Tags: c

Why do I get a  from the console with the following code?

```
 char array1[] = "Hello World";

 char ch = array1;
 printf(" %s" , ch);
```

(We are instructed not to do this with a pointer)

Comment: How is it that you've been instructed not to do this with a pointer, but the error was that you were missing a `*` from pointer notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you need to make ch a *pointer* to a character.  The compiler should have given you a warning that you were assigning a character pointer to a character variable, *and* it should have warned you that you were trying to `printf("%s")` on a non-character-pointer variable -- if it didn't, you should turn up your compiler's warning level!

Just adding that one little, easily-forgotten star makes it work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char array1[] = "Hello World\n";

    char *ch = array1; printf(" %s" , ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I also took the liberty of adding a newline on the end of your string and putting it in a proper `main` function, for the sake of completeness.

---

I just noticed that you said you "aren't allowed to do this with pointers" -- pretty much the only other way to do it is to print out character-by-character until you hit a null terminator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char array1[] = "Hello World\n";

    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; array1[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", array1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ ./a.out
Hello World
```

A more robust approach would be to also put a limit on how many characters you will print out, but just checking for `\0` is probably fine enough for what seems to be a homework assignment.

Comment: Mark, I've entered the above code, but Im trying to check the 4th element in this string with 
printf("%s", s[3]);
but the project freezes on me =(

Comment: @metashockwave s[3] is a character refrence so you need to change the %s to %c to print just that character.

Comment: why not printf( "%s", array1 );?